# Find the actual Data Type of the properties from JSON object in ASP.NET Core

Tags: json, asp.net-core-webapi, model-validation

In my program, I have an ActionFilter class for model validation. The action filter is working fine to validate the model. But the problem is before validating the JSON object, JSON.Net deserialize the JSON object and I need to know the data type of the property of that JSON Object. Can anyone please give me the suggestion, how I can find the data type of the properties in the JSON object. My Action Filter class is below:

```
public class MyModelValidatorFilter: IActionFilter
{   
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.ModelState.IsValid)
            return;

        var errors = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();

        foreach (var err in actionContext.ModelState)
        {
            var itemErrors = new List<string>();

            foreach (var error in err.Value.Errors){
                itemErrors.Add(error.Exception.Message);
            }

            errors.Add(err.Key, itemErrors.ToArray());
        }

        actionContext.Result = new OkObjectResult(new MyResponse
        {
            Errors = errors
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean that you want to analyze the raw json? You can read it from context.HttpContext.Request.Body with StreamReader. But probably it is better to create a custom ModelBinder since you want to do a custom deserialization.

Comment: @Pavel Agarkov, thanks for your answer. Can you please give me some examples or links for that.

Comment: [model binbing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding)